# transfer data via POST to webserver with C# Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, httpclient

I'm trying to transfer data from my Windows Store Application to my webserver via POST.
I tried the following:

```
            try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            Stream stream = GenerateSampleStream(500);
            StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "address/script.php");

            request.Content = streamContent;
            request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true; // Assume we do not know the content length
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        }
private static MemoryStream GenerateSampleStream(int size)
        {
            // Generate sample data.
            byte[] subData = new byte[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < subData.Length; i++)
            {
                subData[i] = 64; // '@'
            }

            return new MemoryStream(subData);
        }
```

Looking at my script.php I do not get any POST data:

```
if($_POST)   {
mail(...);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify: 1. Are you getting any data (i.e. does the PHP code you show even get triggered?) 2. When you have "address" there at the top, that's actually the address of your server? If you use Metro IE to hit that server, do you get a response? 3. If you run Fiddler, do you see the request leaving the client? Can you paste the header information?

Comment: 1. it gets triggerd. I have an else clause which also sends me a mail.
2. It's the direct address to the php-file. Metro IE is all fine!
3. Fiddler shows result 200 and the request is fine.
I'm not used to fiddler that much, where can I find the header information?

Comment: I just tried some settings in fiddler and I figured out that he 500 characters are sent (Inspectors->TextView). But my PHP-script seems not to find them. What header should I use?

Comment: You should be able to copy/paste the entire header - I want to see if it's post or not. http://i.imgur.com/D3XKnOe.png

Comment: It is: POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1

Comment: That means the client at least is sending the data as POST. Your error is (probably) in the server then. Once the call arrives at the proxy (Fiddler), there's no more control the client can really exert. The only 2 options I can see are: 1. There's something corrupt on the request which makes PHP think it's post or 2. Your PHP code is not written correctly. My suggestion is this: Write some simple code in technology you know well(php?)to post to your server.If that works as expected, compare the 2 headers and see if something stands out.If nothing stands out,add the full headers to your post.

Comment: rather - makes PHP think it's NOT post.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/mU6xLJm) -> that's the call via my application.
[link](http://imgur.com/ltXeynz) -> that's a simple form submit with post data

seems in the first one something is missing? - Do you know how to add the needed information to C# HttpClient?

Comment: My gut says that the issue is the fact that your content-type is not set. Try using FormUrlEncodedContent to do your post instead of the random stream. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent.aspx

Comment: great, thanks! Thats working fine for textual information! Do you know how to send an image? / How to change the content type to image?

Comment: Set the ContentType to be "image" or "image/jpeg" or whatever the appropriate mime type is,